# Why is loop not stopping in seperate thread?

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, python-multithreading

I am trying to build a simple video application with tkinter and using OpenCV. I am using threading to capture video frames from the camera, convert them to PIL images and set them as an image in the Tkinter label. The application works perfectly fine including the buttons although problems arise when I try to close the Tkinter window. I use a protocol to do it, and I set the global variable `enablecam` to false, which should stop the loop and the camera, but instead, it just closes the Tkinter window and the video camera continues to run. I tried logging the variable to the console as well, but once the Tkinter window is closed the program stops logging the output to the console. I am not sure why or how this is happening, but I suspect it could have to do with global variables. I have also tried `root.quit()` instead of `root.destroy()` but that just crashes the window.
Here is the code for the application -

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time
from imutils.video import VideoStream

img = cv2.imread('img_avatar.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img2 = Image.fromarray(img)
enablecam = True
print(img2)

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text="Video Camera Application")
label.grid(row=0, column=0)

img3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)

image = tk.Label(root, image=img3)
image.grid(row=1, column=0)


def capture_video():
    video = VideoStream().start()
    time.sleep(2)

    global img2, enablecam, image, img3, img

    while enablecam:
        frame = video.read()

        try:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img2 = Image.fromarray(frame)

            img3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
            image.configure(image=img3)
            image.image = img3
        except Exception as e:
            video.stop()
            break
    img2 = Image.fromarray(img)

    img3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
    image.configure(image=img3)
    image.image = img3
    video.stop()


use_camera = threading.Thread(target=capture_video)
use_camera.start()


def handleCam():
    global use_camera, enablecam, img3, img2, image, img
    if enablecam:
        enablecam = False
        img2 = Image.fromarray(img)

        img3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
        image.configure(image=img3)
        image.image = img3
    else:
        enablecam = True
        use_camera = threading.Thread(target=capture_video)
        use_camera.start()


cambtn = tk.Button(text='Enable Cam', command=handleCam)
cambtn.grid(row=2, column=0)


def on_closing():
    global enablecam, img3, img2, image, img, root

    if enablecam:
        enablecam = False
        img2 = Image.fromarray(img)

        img3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
        image.configure(image=img3)
        image.image = img3

    root.destroy()


root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

root.mainloop()
```

It would be great if you could help me fix this issue, Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't update your UI from outside the main thread.  You need to use `root.after` to fire a function in the main thread.  You should do  `use_camera.join()` after you stop things to make sure the thread exits.  But really, what you should do is throw away `Tkinter`.  It has always been a hack, and Python has tried to get rid of it for many years.  Use a real UI framework, like Qt or wxWidgets.

Comment: But the above code example works, and I am able to update the Tkinter UI from a separate thread. The problem arises when I try to exit the program, the video feed doesn't stop

Comment: Change `root.destroy()` to `root.after(100, root.destroy)` inside `on_closing()` function to let tkinter handles pending events.

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't work

Comment: It works for me, may be adjust the value `100` to larger value and try again.

Comment: Or call `root.update()` to force tkinter to handle pending events before `root.destroy()` inside `on_closing()`.

Comment: I tried both of them, neither solution works for me

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because the while loop is not getting any command `enablecam = False`. Keep that in the loop and I think it should work.

Comment: where can I add this in the loop?

Comment: Hey, my bad,  I didn't understand it before. But acw1668's `root.after(100, root.destroy)` and `root.update` both are working fine.